# Bind a click event to a tap

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I'm making a responsive site that has a `:hover` effect on its central links.  Works great on PC but on mobile it requires two taps to get to the link action.

Is there a way that I can selectively bind a tap event or `touchstart` to the same functionality of `click` event, only on mobile?

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty:

```
$(".selector").on('touchstart'){
    $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

This will target touches on laptops, etc. with touchscreens as well. This experience should be consistent among devices.

---

Of course, it would be cleaner to bind events to both `click` and `touchstart` from the get-go:

```
$('.selector').on('click touchstart', function(){
    ...
```

Comment: thank you!  Do you know how to unbind it, so that if a user resizes their browser the normal functionality resumes?

Comment: To unbind $('.selector').off('touchstart'); this will unbind all touch start handlers from element. To selectively unbind use $('.selector').on('touchstart.someidentifier',callback) and $('.selector').off('touchstart.someidentifier')